# Quantikz gategroup not working

Tags: diagrams, quantikz

I am trying to re-write the Grover search algorithm using `quantikz`. I was trying to highlight the inner group of operations (basically the whole circuit except for first and last column) using `\gategroup`, but the error `no shape named tikzf@1@-col3 is known` appears, and the grouping box does not render properly. Any suggestions?

This is the latex code I wrote

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{tikz} % for quantum circuits
\usetikzlibrary{quantikz} % for quantum circuits


\begin{document}

\begin{quantikz}
\lstick{$\ket{0}$} & \gate{H}  & \gate[wires=4]{U_\omega}  \gategroup[wires=4,steps=4,style={dotted,cap=round,inner sep=7pt}, label style={label position=below, yshift = -0.5cm}]{repeat $r(N)$ times} &  \gate{H} & \gate[wires=4]{2\ket{0}\bra{0}-I} & \gate{H} & \meter{}\\
\lstick{$\ket{0}$} & \gate{H} & {} & \gate{H} & {} & \gate{H} & \meter{}\\
\lstick{$\vdots$} & \push{...} & {} & \push{...} & {} & \push{...} &  \meter{}\\
\lstick{$\ket{0}$} & \gate{H} & {} & \gate{H} & {} &\gate{H} &\meter{} \\
\end{quantikz}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SX! It may feel a bit counterintuitive, but you should not add `\\​` to the last line:

```
\documentclass[border=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{quantikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{quantikz}
\lstick{$\ket{0}$} & \gate{H} & \gate[wires=4]{U_\omega}  \gategroup[wires=4, steps=4, style={dotted, cap=round, inner sep=7pt}, label style={label position=below, yshift=-0.5cm}]{repeat $r(N)$ times} & \gate{H} & \gate[wires=4]{2\ket{0}\bra{0}-I} & \gate{H} & \meter{} \\
\lstick{$\ket{0}$} & \gate{H} & {} & \gate{H} & {} & \gate{H} & \meter{}\\
\lstick{$\vdots$} & \push{...} & {} & \push{...} & {} & \push{...} & \meter{}\\
\lstick{$\ket{0}$} & \gate{H} & {} & \gate{H} & {} &\gate{H} &\meter{} 
\end{quantikz}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Oh! Thank you a lot!